# TeamCity Build Agent name is not picked up from config file

Tags: azure, teamcity, azure-virtual-machine

I have recently setup a VM on azure to use as my build agent.
When the agent is started its name is calculated based on the azure instance name (_myservername) and the name I provide in the `buildAgent.properties` file is ignored completely.

This is particularly problematic when I have a second agent and the same name is chosen which will result in name conflict.

looking at the `teamcity-agent.log` I can see the following lines:

```
[2016-07-14 15:33:04,745]   WARN - ds.azure.AzurePropertiesReader - Unable to set self port. Azure integration will experience problems 
[2016-07-14 15:33:04,745]   INFO - ds.azure.AzurePropertiesReader - Added alternative address is set to  
[2016-07-14 15:33:04,745]   INFO - ds.azure.AzurePropertiesReader - Instance name and agent name are set to _myservername
...
```

Question is:

- Why is the name I provide via config file is not taking precedence over any other place it reads the name from? -- should it?
- How can I possibly force a name on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the came to find the answer to this and would share it here in case it would be useful for the humans of the future!

The issue was caused by the the `azure-plugin` where it was setting a `configuration-parameter` on the agent called `instance name`.

https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-azure-plugin/issues/17

The issue is fixed in the latest version of the plugin so upgrading it solved my problem. :)